# How can I smooth or ignore small changes in a variable in R?

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a variable for which I'd like to ignore small changes, up to a threshold of 5, since I interpret them as measurement error or noise.

My minimal data is:

```
mydf = data.frame(time = 1:14,
                  variable=c(1,1,1,4,1,1,1,7,6,5,5,4,5,25))
```

I've attempted to smooth out these small changes using the following approach:

```
mydf %>%
  mutate(previous = lag(variable, n = 1, default = first(variable)),
         mytry = ifelse(abs(previous - variable) < 5, previous, variable)) 

   time variable previous   mytry 
1     1        1        1       1
2     2        1        1       1
3     3        1        1       1
4     4        4        1       1  <- from time 3 to 4 a small change happened
5     5        1        4       4  <- this should also be 1
6     6        1        1       1
7     7        1        1       1
8     8        7        1       7  <- initial big change
9     9        6        7       7  <- first small change ignored
10   10        5        6       6  <- second small change comes back in
11   11        5        5       5
12   12        4        5       5
13   13        5        4       4
14   14       25        5      25
```

From the solution above, I can correctly identify the first small change and ignore it. But if a second small change comes after, it's still in my smoothed variable. How can I prevent this? I think it's best to set any big change as a new base value and compared to this, ignore small changes. The minimal data should look like this:

```
   time variable previous   mytry optimal5
1     1        1        1       1         1
2     2        1        1       1         1
3     3        1        1       1         1
4     4        4        1       1         1 
5     5        1        4       4         1  
6     6        1        1       1         1
7     7        1        1       1         1
8     8        7        1       7         7 
9     9        6        7       7         7 
10   10        5        6       6         7 
11   11        5        5       5         7
12   12        4        5       5         7
13   13        5        4       4         7
14   14       25        5      25         25
```

Here is the visualization that shows how the first small changes is ignored.

[image]

Comment: did you try using a larger window? ie. making "variable" by taking the mean of, let's say 5(?)  surrounding values. then 2 small changes would be smoothed over more effectively

Comment: Can you think of a code for your approach? Since rolling operations often use the mean, and the mean is distorted by outlier, i.e. big changes, I did not use it so far.

Comment: yes. you could check if `value-mean` is smaller than the threshhold. if so set it to the value of the most frequent number. i think it can work but didn't test it - anyway, i like @r2evans answer more than my idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your condition is solely based on the difference being less than 5, then we need to do a *reduction*. It cannot be done in a vectorized operation since the value of a row relies on the previous value, which may be updated.

Try this:

```r
fun <- function(prev, this) if (abs(this-prev) < 5) prev else this
mydf %>%
  mutate(
    smoothed = Reduce(fun, variable, accumulate = TRUE)
  )
#    time variable smoothed
# 1     1        1        1
# 2     2        1        1
# 3     3        1        1
# 4     4        4        1
# 5     5        1        1
# 6     6        1        1
# 7     7        1        1
# 8     8        7        7
# 9     9        6        7
# 10   10        5        7
# 11   11        5        7
# 12   12        4        7
# 13   13        5        7
# 14   14       25       25
```

I used a named-function for demonstration, but it works just fine with an inline anonymous function (which was present in the first edit of this answer).

If we unroll the calls to `fun` from `Reduce(..)`, it would look like this:

```r
fun(1, 1) -> 1
fun(1, 1) -> 1
fun(1, 4) -> 1
fun(1, 1) -> 1
fun(1, 1) -> 1
fun(1, 1) -> 1
fun(1, 7) -> 7
fun(7, 6) -> 7
...
```

The default action of `Reduce` is to return just the last value; adding `accumulate=TRUE` provides all intermediate values as well.

Comment: Well, this is a lot shorter than my approach. Thank you. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

For sure there must be a more effective way to do it than a loop, but I can't see how you can do it outside of storing the value in an external vector...

This works for me, but if you have a massive data.frame it might now be the best.

```r
library(data.table)

mydf = data.frame(time = 1:14,
                  variable=c(1,1,1,4,1,1,1,7,6,5,5,4,5,25)) |> setDT()

value_vect <- mydf[1,variable]
mydf[1,value := value_vect] 

 for(i in 2:nrow(mydf)){
   value_vect <- if_else(abs(mydf[i-1,variable] - mydf[i,variable]) < 5, value_vect, mydf[i,variable])
   mydf[i,value := value_vect]
 }

mydf
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But as you say, I'd rather prefer some `data.table` approach to be faster than the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a version with `data.table` that seems to be correct and very fast (takes a second on about 200.000 observations). I decided to create several intermediate variables like this

```
library(data.table)

mydf <- data.frame(time = 1:14,
                   variable = c(1, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 1, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 5, 25)) |> setDT()

# Calculate differences between consecutive values
mydf[, diff_var := c(NA, diff(variable))]

# Identify groups where differences are greater than or equal to 5
mydf[, large_change := abs(diff_var) >= 5]

# Replace NA values with FALSE in the large_change column
mydf[is.na(large_change), large_change := FALSE]

# Create groups based on consecutive TRUE values
mydf[, group := rleid(large_change)]

# Calculate cumulative sum based on large_change, ignoring the initial NA value
mydf[, cum_large_change := cumsum(large_change)]

# Calculate the smoothed variable within each group
mydf[, smooth_var := first(variable), by = cum_large_change]

mydf

    time variable diff_var large_change group cum_large_change smooth_var
 1:    1        1       NA        FALSE     1                0          1
 2:    2        1        0        FALSE     1                0          1
 3:    3        1        0        FALSE     1                0          1
 4:    4        4        3        FALSE     1                0          1
 5:    5        1       -3        FALSE     1                0          1
 6:    6        1        0        FALSE     1                0          1
 7:    7        1        0        FALSE     1                0          1
 8:    8        7        6         TRUE     2                1          7
 9:    9        6       -1        FALSE     3                1          7
10:   10        5       -1        FALSE     3                1          7
11:   11        5        0        FALSE     3                1          7
12:   12        4       -1        FALSE     3                1          7
13:   13        5        1        FALSE     3                1          7
14:   14       25       20         TRUE     4                2         25
```

[image]